# Pivot Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I´ve got a DataFrame made from a list of 'three lists'
Then I obtain a DataFrame [3 rows x 25 columns]

It comes from

tabla_datos = [lista_archivos_disponibles_index,valores_este,valores_norte]

lista_archivos_disponibles_index is a list of Strings

I would like to use the lista_archivos_disponibles_index like the index in a new DataFrame of [25 rows x 3 columns]

still on

MED_an201509020600  MED_fc201509020603  MED_fc201509020606  \
0            0.414020           -0.024724            1.658653
1           -0.882412            0.002801            1.807558

now it is a dictionary but I would like to use the first line as key

as:

```
MED_an201509020600   0.414020           -0.024724

MED_fc201509020603 -0.882412            0.002801
```

using the firts row as index

thanks

Comment: You want lista_archivos_disponibles_index to be the index for a completely new set of data or as an index for the existing valores_este and valores_norte?

Comment: Yes. That is my question

Answer (score 0):

```
new_data_frame = [[tabla_datos[v][i] for v in range(len(tabla_datos))] for i, x in enumerate(tabla_datos[0])]
```